# multiple sql statment within 1 class

Tags: php

I'm new in OOP php and I am trying to create a simple add to cart function where when the user adds a product to the cart the product id will be inserted to the cart table and I want to fetch the product price from the post table based on product id in the cart table to be added to the cart price column,the product id is inserted into the cart table but I can't get the price.

```
<?php
class Post{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function getprice($id){
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE id = :id');
        $this->db->bind(':pirce', $price);

        $results = $this->db->resultSet();
        return $results;
    }


    //add to cart
    public function addcart($data){

        $price = $this->getprice($id);

        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO cart (p_id,  size ,price) VALUE (:id, :qty, $price)');

        //bind values
        $this->db->bind(':id', $data['id']);
        $this->db->bind(':qty', $data['qty']);
        $this->db->bind($price);

        // Execute
        if($this->db->execute()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

[cart table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1ijL.png)

[post table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI1qX.png)

Comment: What is the getprice($id) fn returns. and is this         $this->db->bind(':pirce', $price); is correct in the getprice function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
class Post{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function getprice($id){
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE id = :id');
        $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

        $results = $this->db->resultSet();
        return $results;
    }


    //add to cart
    public function addcart($data){

        $post = $this->getprice($data['id']);

        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO cart (p_id,  size ,price) VALUE (:id, :qty, :price)');

        //bind values
        $this->db->bind(':id', $data['id']);
        $this->db->bind(':qty', $data['qty']);
        $this->db->bind(':price', $post->price);

        // Execute
        if($this->db->execute()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer the $this->db->resultSet(); is a (PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: i am getting Notice: Undefined variable: id and Notice: Undefined variable: price

Comment: I am getting and error message( Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' )

Comment: Thank you so much it works.... i just edited $this->db->bind(':price', $post->price); to  $this->db->bind(':price', $post[0]->price);

Comment: If my answer was useful please vote and check it as answer. thanks. @J.Doe